# How to get parameter type in reflected class method (PHP 5.x)?

Tags: php, reflection, parameters, php-5.4

I'm trying to get type `$bar` variable.

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    public function test(stdClass $bar, array $foo)
    {

    }
}

$reflect = new ReflectionClass('Foo');
foreach ($reflect->getMethods() as $method) {
    foreach ($method->getParameters() as $num => $parameter) {
        var_dump($parameter->getType());
    }
}
```

I expect `stdClass` but I get

```
Call to undefined method ReflectionParameter::getType()
```

What can be wrong? Or there is some another way?..

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.4.41 (cli) (built: May 14 2015 02:34:29)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

**UPD1**
It should work for the array type as well.

Comment: [getType()](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionparameter.gettype.php) is available in PHP 7.

Comment: Ups... Thanks for this note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like similar question already added in
[PHP Reflection - Get Method Parameter Type As String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513867/php-reflection-get-method-parameter-type-as-string)

I wrote my solution it works for all cases:

```
/**
 * @param ReflectionParameter $parameter
 * @return string|null
 */
function getParameterType(ReflectionParameter $parameter)
{
    $export = ReflectionParameter::export(
        array(
            $parameter->getDeclaringClass()->name,
            $parameter->getDeclaringFunction()->name
        ),
        $parameter->name,
        true
    );
    return preg_match('/[>] ([A-z]+) /', $export, $matches)
        ? $matches[1] : null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're only type hinting classes, you can use [`->getClass()`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionparameter.getclass.php) which is supported in PHP 5 and 7.

```
<?php

class MyClass {

}

class Foo
{
    public function test(stdClass $bar)
    {

    }

    public function another_test(array $arr) {

    }

    public function final_test(MyClass $var) {

    }
}

$reflect = new ReflectionClass('Foo');
foreach ($reflect->getMethods() as $method) {
    foreach ($method->getParameters() as $num => $parameter) {
        var_dump($parameter->getClass());
    }
}
```

The reason I say classes, is because on an array, it will return NULL.

[Output](https://eval.in/private/f3247877fe9907):

```
object(ReflectionClass)#6 (1) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(8) "stdClass"
}
NULL
object(ReflectionClass)#6 (1) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(7) "MyClass"
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it works. Thanks! So, `$parameter->getClass() ? $parameter->getClass()->name : null;`. I don't know why didn't notice that.) Seem it's too late, 9pm. :)

Comment: I mentioned it as one of the caveats, if this is important either (1) upgrade to php 7, or (2) use `->export` and mangle raw source code text with regex.